# How to draw bar charts for very small values in python or matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I drawn the comparison bar chart for very small values with the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[ 0.00790019035339353, 0.00002112],
    [0.0107705593109131, 0.0000328540802001953],
    [0.0507792949676514, 0.0000541210174560547]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.plot.bar()

plt.bar(df['A'], df['B'])
plt.show()
```

Due to very small values I can't visualise the chart colour for the ('B' column) smaller value (e.g. 0.00002112)  in the graph.

[image]

How can I modify the code to visualise smaller value(B column) colour in the graph? Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common way to display data with different orders of magnitude is 
to use a logarithmic scaling for the y-axis. Below the logarithm
to base 10 is used but other bases could be chosen.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[ 0.00790019035339353, 0.00002112],
        [0.0107705593109131, 0.0000328540802001953],
        [0.0507792949676514, 0.0000541210174560547]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.plot.bar()

plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Update:
To change the formatting of the yaxis labels an instance of  `ScalarFormatter` can be used:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

data = [[ 0.00790019035339353, 0.00002112],
        [0.0107705593109131, 0.0000328540802001953],
        [0.0507792949676514, 0.0000541210174560547]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
df.plot.bar()

plt.yscale("log")
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much LuckyJosh.. This is also a good option to draw like this kind of graph.. Thanks..

Comment: LuckyJosh:- The graph output visualisation point of view your solution is very good and easy one. Is there any option to display the the y axis value in the form of exact value (like 0.00002112 ) rather than 10^-4. If it is possible means try to guide fractional part digit length to display(like 0.00 or 0.00000). If means it will helpful for future. Thanks..

Comment: You can (I will add a way to my answer when I have time), however in general I would not advise you to do this. If you require the exact value it should be placed in a Tabel of some sorts, plots are good for comparison and visualizing trends, but not for data retrieval.

Comment: Sure.. I take your advise. My requirement is to compare the 2 values and want to understand the output by novice people also. So only I request you the numerical and digit based X,Y axis values. While your free time you can share your answer. Thanks for your response..

Comment: Do you want to have the exact values on the y-axis or do you just want to chage the formatting from scientific notation to decimal notation (0.001 instead of 10^-3)?

Comment: Not exact value..  just want to change the formatting from scientific notation to decimal notation (0.001 instead of 10^-3).. That is enough..Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

You could create 2 y-axis like this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
width = 0.2
df['A'].plot(kind='bar', color='green', ax=ax1, width=width, position=1, label = 'A')
df['B'].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, width=width, position=0, label = 'B')

ax1.set_ylabel('A')
ax2.set_ylabel('B')

# legend
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]