# How to plot small values in python chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` to draw a bar graph from csv files. The graph is drawn successfully.
I am plotting some values on X axis. However, when I have for example this data:

```
A = 10
B = 2000,000
```

The A bar does not appear on the graph because its value is too small. I need to show A bar even if it is too small, what should I do?
What is the method that should I change its value?

I used the following:

```
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(axis='x')
plt.grid(which='minor',axis='x',linestyle=':',linewidth=0.6)
```

I looked in the previous question
[How to draw bar charts for very small values in python or matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569576/how-to-draw-bar-charts-for-very-small-values-in-python-or-matplotlib)

I cannot use:

```
plt.xscale("log")
```

because I want to the x axis to contain Time in milliseconds.

[image: Graph Example]

Graph show that A do not have bar because its value is too small.

Comment: This does not provide a complete example. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Comment: But presumably the values of `A` and `B` are shown on the y-axis. I don't understand why you can't give the y-axis a log scale.

Comment: y axis contains the name A and B but X should show the Time in milliseconds. When the scale is small (i.e A = 10 and B = 2000) both bar appear, but when the scale is large (i.e A =10 and B= 2000,000) the A's bar do not show.

Comment: Then it's clear why it doesn't show up. What do you expect? It's 1:200000. Imagine trying to see 1 cm compared to 2 km.

Comment: Yes , but this may mislead the reader and may think A do not have an answer, that why I want to show at least small bar

Comment: still doesn't make any sense. the bar is there, just invisible to naked eye. As BoarGules said, I still don't understand why log scale is forbidden. There is no way one could see 10 if the max value is 2e6. The most you can do is just to add text next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the version with **log scale**

```
a = 2e6
b = 1e1
c = 2e3
data = [a,b,c]
y = np.arange(len(data))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(y,data)
ax.set_xlabel('This is time in ms, still ms, regardless of log scale')
ax.xaxis.grid()
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C'])

for i in range(len(data)):
    ax.text(data[i], y[i]-0.1, f'{int(data[i])}', rotation=90)

ax.set_xscale('log')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment out the last line, then you get **linear scale**

[image]

Without log you will never be able to see the other two.

Forget 10, even 2000 will not be visible. `2e3:2e6` is `1:1000` --> imagine `1cm` in `10m`. Even `1cm` in `1m` would be barely visible.